# C++ polymorphic Print function not resolving properly

Tags: c++, json, arduino, polymorphism, teensy

I have created a class that abstracts a SPI flash chip library called SerialFlash by creating an abstract class of Print.h. When I try to print to this by using the ArduinoJson library, I get an error:

```
src/FlashMemory.cpp:99:36: error: no matching function for call to 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject::printTo(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
root.printTo(serialFlashPrint);
^

lib/ArduinoJson/include/ArduinoJson/Internals/../Internals/JsonPrintable.hpp:34:10: note: size_t ArduinoJson::Internals::JsonPrintable<T>::printTo(Print&) const [with T = Ardu
inoJson::JsonObject; size_t = unsigned int]
size_t printTo(Print &print) const {
^
lib/ArduinoJson/include/ArduinoJson/Internals/../Internals/JsonPrintable.hpp:34:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 
'Print&'
```

The file referenced in the error above is here: https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/blob/master/include/ArduinoJson/Internals/JsonPrintable.hpp

This is the header file for the class:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SerialFlash.h>
#include "Print.h"

#ifndef _SerialFlashPrint_h_
#define _SerialFlashPrint_h_

class SerialFlashPrint : public Print {
  public:
    SerialFlashPrint(SerialFlashFile *file);

    virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
    virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size);

  private:
    char buf[1];
    uint16_t _current_byte;
    SerialFlashFile * _file;
};

#endif
```

And the cpp file:

```
#include "serialFlashPrint.h"

SerialFlashPrint::SerialFlashPrint(SerialFlashFile * file) : Print() {
  this->_file = file;
  this->_current_byte = 0;
}

size_t SerialFlashPrint::write(uint8_t c) {
  if(_current_byte == 0){
    _file->erase();
    _file->seek(0);
  }
  sprintf(buf, "%c", c);
  _file->write(buf, 1);
  _current_byte++;
  return 0;
}

size_t SerialFlashPrint::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size){
  _file->erase();
  _file->seek(0);
  _file->write(buffer, size);
  _file->write(NULL, 1);
  return 0;
};
```

Generally, you use print function as: the root.printTo(Serial). This code is based upon an abstraction (which I got to work previously) called Chunked output that can be seen here: https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/wiki/Bag-of-Tricks

Does anyone have any clues for me to figure out why I am getting `<unresolved overloaded function type>` instead of Print&?

Answer (score 0):

`<unresolved overloaded function type>` means that the compiler found a function with several overloads and doesn't know which one to use.

You most likely have several `serialFlashPrint()` in your code or libraries.

If not, then you may have triggered the [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
SerialFlashPrint serialFlashPrint;   // <- creates an instance of SerialFlashPrint  
SerialFlashPrint serialFlashPrint(); // <- declares a function returning a SerialFlashPrint
```